# Wrong output format with re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, split

I expect this code to print `"ez_setup.py"` instead it printed `"ez_setup\x01"`. Please can someone point me in the right direction.

```
In [7]: url = 'http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/mysqldb-2/ci/default/tree/ez_setup.py?format=raw'
In [8]: url_split = url.split('/')
In [9]: for item in url_split:
   ...:     if ".py" in item:
   ...:         file_name = re.sub(r"(.py).+", "\1", item)

In [10]: file_name
Out[10]: 'ez_setup\x01'
```

Comment: What is `url_split`?

Comment: have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for `\1`:

```
file_name = re.sub(r"(.py).+", r"\1", item)
#                              ^
```

Otherwise, it will be interpreted as an escape sequence:

```
>>> '\1'
'\x01'
>>> r'\1'
'\\1'
>>>
```

Note too that `.` is a special character in Regex patterns.  It tells Python to match *any* character (except a newline).  I think you meant to escape it before `py`:

```
file_name = re.sub(r"(\.py).+", r"\1", item)
```

Now Python will match a literal period.

Comment: or even easier just `re.sub(r"(\.py).+)",".py",item)` using `\\1` doesnt make much sense for this imho